# Any way to define same type alias in two defferent kotlin files?

Tags: kotlin

I have `private typealias CustomerId = UUID` in Customer.kt file. Now I want the same type alias to be defined in another file in the same package but I'm getting a redeclaration error.
Since I declared the typealias as `private` in the Customer.kt file isn't it mean the typealias are only visible to that file?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem that is reported as **[KT-24700](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24700)**. Unfortunately, I don't think they will fix it any time soon, given that it was reported 5 years ago.

I've also tested this on my own Kotlin playground, and I experience the same behaviour as you.

#### References:

- **[Problems with TypeAlias](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/problems-with-typealias/10753)**